# why does std repeat trait bound between impl block and associated function?

Tags: rust

why is `A: allocator` in both the `impl` line and in the `where` of `new_in`? Is it just for documentation to have the trait bound visible in the docs for the individual method, or would the meaning be different if the `where` bound was omitted?

in this snippet from https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#378-380

````
impl<T, A: Allocator> Box<T, A> {
    /// Allocates memory in the given allocator then places `x` into it.
    ///
    /// This doesn't actually allocate if `T` is zero-sized.
    ///
    /// # Examples
    ///
    /// ```
    /// #![feature(allocator_api)]
    ///
    /// use std::alloc::System;
    ///
    /// let five = Box::new_in(5, System);
    /// ```
    #[cfg(not(no_global_oom_handling))]
    #[unstable(feature = "allocator_api", issue = "32838")]
    #[must_use]
    #[inline]
    pub fn new_in(x: T, alloc: A) -> Self
    where
        A: Allocator,
    {
        let mut boxed = Self::new_uninit_in(alloc);
        unsafe {
            boxed.as_mut_ptr().write(x);
            boxed.assume_init()
        }
    }
````

Comment: Good question. I don't know if this was intentional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a leftover.

[Originally, the bounds were only on the `impl`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/69ac533527025fffa37ad1bc4d82b3bc65f90264/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs#L333-L357). But then, in [PR #91884](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/91884), `new_in` was (conditionally, depending on the `const`ness of the allocator) `const`ified, and therefore the `A: Allocator` on the impl was no longer enough - it needed to become `A: ~const Allocator` (a maybe-`const` bound), which can only be put on the method. But then, design issues were raised about the const traits feature, that caused its usage in std to be removed, including from `Box` in [PR #109693](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/109693). In that PR, only the `~const` was removed and the bound was left as-is, leaving a redundant bound.